# using scrlayer-scrpage, get different header on title page

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

A place where I want to submit a paper requires the following.

- A certain header on the title page,
- the abstract not on the title, but the second page
- a different header from page 2 onward
- page number displayed on all pages including title pages (as counting title page as 1).

This sounds easy enough. I originally attempted this with `fancyhdr`, now switched to `scrlayer-scrpage` because I read that `fancyhdr` should not go with KOMA, but still cannot get it to work. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in}

\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\linespread{2}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \clearpairofpagestyles

\begin{document}

\ihead{\normalfont Running Head: This header to be only on title page}
\chead{}
\ohead{\normalfont \thepage }

\setcounter{page}{1}

\title{mytitle}
\author{Donald Duck}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
\begin{center}
Abstract
\end{center}
Abstract text...
\end{abstract}

\newpage


\ihead{\normalfont This header to appear from abstract page onward}
\chead{}
\ohead{ \normalfont \thepage}

\section{Introduction}

Begin text here.

\end{document}
```

As of now, there are no headers on the title and abstract page, and the header that is supposed to start on page 2 only starts at page 3.

**What are the commands necessary to display two different headers on the title page and "abstract page"?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With option `titlepage` command `\maketitle` uses environment `titlepage` that uses `\thispagestyle{empty}`. This is independent from using `fancyhdr` or `scrlayer-scrpage` (and even the same with `article` instead of `scrartcl`).

For the head of the title page you can use `\titlehead`. If it should not be part of the text area but of the page margin, you can move it up using `\vspace*` and `\vspace` with negative values.

The centered abstract head can be set automatically using option `abstract`. But with option `titlepage` the `abstract` environment is also a `titlepage` environment. So it uses `\thispagestyle{empty}` too. In the following example I use an explicit `\thispagestyle{headings}` in the `abstract` environment to change the page style of the abstract page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,abstract,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in}

\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\linespread{2}

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}% not special font for page head and foot
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\markright{This header to appear from abstract page onward}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\begin{document}

\titlehead{\vspace*{-\headsep}\vspace{-\headheight}\vspace{-\topskip}
  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{%
    Running Head: This header to be only on title page%
%    \hfill\pagemark% activate if page number should be shown
  }%
}
\title{mytitle}
\author{Donald Duck}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{headings}
Abstract text...
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Begin text here.

\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image: titlepage and abstract page]

An alternative would be, to change the page style of the title page. You can use again `\titlehead` to achieve this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,abstract,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in}

\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\linespread{2}

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}% not special font for page head and foot
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\begin{document}

\markright{Running Head: This header to be only on title page}
\titlehead{\thispagestyle{headings}}
\title{mytitle}
\author{Donald Duck}

\maketitle

\markright{This header to appear from abstract page onward}
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{headings}
Abstract text...
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Begin text here.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, both of these work. Now, on a side note, do you also know ho the abstract can go to the top of the page instead of centered?

Comment: @Marie.P. Either use `xpatch` to remove `\null\vfil` from `\abstract` (this is the begin command of `abstract` environment) or don't use the `abstract` environment. If you need more help for the `abstract` please ask another question, if you cannot find one.